# How do you unit test JavaScript written in Asynchronous Module Definition pattern?

Tags: javascript, amd, ts-jest

I tried to add a unit test framework (JEST) to legacy JavaScript codebase written in AMD.
NodeJs kicks out an error when require to add the module.

Here is the JavaScript AMD:

```
define('LegacyModule',
function () {
    'use strict';        
    var exports = {
        CreateTag: function (name) {
            return 'tag:' + name;
        },
    };
    return exports;
});
```

Here is the Test file:

```
require('amd-loader');
var myTest = require('./LegacyModule');

test('Create where tag does not throw exception', () => {
    var request = myTest.CreateTag('test');
    expect(request.toBe('tag:test'));
});
```

Here are the errors:

> Test suite failed to run
> Can not assign module to a different id than the current file
> ● Test suite failed to run

```
Can not assign module to a different id than the current file

  1 | define('LegacyModule',
> 2 |     function () {
    |                 ^
  3 |         'use strict';
  4 |         var exports = {
  5 |

  at Object.<anonymous>.global.define (node_modules/amd-loader/amd-loader.js:39:15)
```

Comment: Post the error here as actual text, not as a link to an image

Comment: The `amd-loader` you're using [appears to be 8 years old](https://github.com/guybedford/amd-loader). NodeJS has changed so much since then so I'm surprised it even runs at all.

Comment: @Dai Is there a newer one that I should be using?

Comment: @Pointy Updated with text

Comment: @Dai that's not the correct module though, [it's this one](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-amd-loader/)

Comment: @MinusFour Are you sure about that? There appear to be multiple different implementations of AMD loaders for NodeJS, all containing the "Can not assign module..." string embedded in them.

Comment: @Dai yes, the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amd-loader) has that repository as its source.

Answer (score 0):

The [amd-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amd-loader) library does not seem to work. It throws an error at [this line](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-amd-loader/blob/88faa40184d5ae8f58eeec34fcb8ec29bcda53ca/amd-loader.js#L39):

```
// id is 'LegacyModule' while mod.id is a full file name of a Jest unit test
// they don't match and error is thrown
if (typeof id === "string" && id !== mod.id) {
        throw new Error("Can not assign module to a different id than the current file");
}
```

However I was able to mock `define()` with Jest without using `amd-loader` library and extract the function from AMD code.

```
global.define = jest.fn(); // declare 'define' function
require('./LegacyModule'); // AMD module will call define(id, implementation)
const LegacyModule = global.define.mock.calls[0][1]; // gets 'implementation'
const myTest = LegacyModule();

test('Create where tag does not throw exception', () => {
    var request = myTest.CreateTag('test');
    expect(request).toBe('tag:test');
});
```